# Javascript : Scroll to top to the div when enter key is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollbar

I am having one issue regarding scrolltop. I am using react js Scrollbars library for my task.
When I scroll down and press the enter key in textbox then there should be a scrolltop to that div.

I have used below code for my task.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars'

class ScrollBarTask extends React.Component {

handleUserInput = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            var element = document.querySelector('.parentDiv')
              element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
              element.scrollTop = 0;
        }
    }
  render(){
    return(
      
      <div>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value..." value={} onKeyPress={e => this.handleUserInput(e)}
                            />
        <Scrollbars style={{ height: window.innerHeight - 110), clear: "both", backgroundColor: '#EBECED' }} autoHide={true}>
        <div className="parentDiv">
          <div>dummy data</div><br><br><br><br>
          <div>dummy data</div><br><br><br><br>
          <div>dummy data</div><br><br><br><br>
          <div>dummy data</div><br><br><br><br>
          <div>dummy data</div><br><br><br><br>
          <div>dummy data</div><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
        </Scrollbars>
      </div>
    
    )
  }
}

export default ScrollBarTask
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

any help would be great.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars'

class ScrollBarTask extends React.Component {

handleUserInput = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            var element = document.getElementById('parentDivID').scrollIntoView({ block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' });
        }
    }
  render(){
    return(
      
      <div>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value..." value={} onKeyPress={e => this.handleUserInput(e)}
                            />
        <Scrollbars style={{ height: window.innerHeight - 110), clear: "both", backgroundColor: '#EBECED' }} autoHide={true}>
        <div className="parentDiv" id="parentDivID">
          <div>dummy data</div><br><br><br><br>
          <div>dummy data</div><br><br><br><br>
          <div>dummy data</div><br><br><br><br>
          <div>dummy data</div><br><br><br><br>
          <div>dummy data</div><br><br><br><br>
          <div>dummy data</div><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
        </Scrollbars>
      </div>
    
    )
  }
}

export default ScrollBarTask
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

For smooth scrolling you can refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) link.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this in your function :

```
document.getElementById('youridhere').scrollIntoView();
```

You can then animate the scroll to your wish

Comment: thank you for your answer. just one thing. is there any way to scroll smoothly? I mean is there any inbuilt function for the same?